# The procedure entry point WSCSetApplicationCategory could not be located in the dynamic link library WS2_32.dll

Tags: wine

When starting an application using Wine, I got the following error:

```
The procedure entry point WSCSetApplicationCategory could not be located 
in the dynamic link library WS2_32.dll
```

Looking into the [WineAPI](https://source.winehq.org/WineAPI/ws2_32.html), the library really seems to be missing this. Quite naively, I tried to download the dll from [here](https://www.dll-files.com/ws2_32.dll.html), but it didn't help either.

Is there any way how to get this application running?

Comment: This was introduced in Vista; could you try running the application with the “Windows Version” set to an older release (in `winecfg`)?

Comment: `This application is not designed to run on your Windows version. Please update to Windows 7 or newer.` I guess somebody is trolling me here.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Some applications can run on a variety of versions, and will only try to find LSP functions in Vista or later; that’s not the case here...

Comment: So does it mean I am (most probably) unlucky and have no other way to run it than to install Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Wine currently doesn’t implement `WSCSetApplicationCategory`, but given what it’s [supposed to do](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ws2spi/nf-ws2spi-wscsetapplicationcategory), it could be sufficient to add a stub:

```
@ stub WSCSetApplicationCategory
```

in `dlls/ws2_32/ws2_32.spec` in the Wine source (and then you need to rebuild...).

Comment: Now wine has that API's stub implementation.